# Sequelize Date column still return as UTC when useUTC: false

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I'm using nestjs, sequelize-typescript and postgresql database.
When I Post data, it saved correctly with timezone (+07:00)
But when I get the data, the date column returned as UTC timezone.

For example, I post this date

> 2018-11-22 17:00:00

In the database, it saved as

> 2018-11-22 17:00:00 +7

But when I get/call the data, it gives me this result

> 2018-11-22T10:00:00.000Z

I have been trying to google it a whole day and most people suggest to add this line in the database config

```
timezone: '+07:00',
dialectOptions: {
    useUTC: false
}
```

But it still not working.

Comment: how are you querying the database?

Comment: I'm using built-in sequelize function, like findbyid, and findone.
if look into the log, it just execute simple select with join.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53563297/10728931) answer. Note that `2018-11-22T10:00:00.000Z` and `2018-11-22 17:00:00 +7` is a same date. Sequelize return a js Date object, that you can format as you like. By default in console you see date formated as ISO string.