# How to read and store datetime as is from javascript to mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, sequelize.js, momentjs

I am building an application node.js where a user creates a record with a field named tour date and time. I am using [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com) plugin to show the date and time dropdown window. Once the user saves the record it is saved in the MySQL table as datetime field.

Then I am using [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io) to display all the tour dates for a given month-year.

But here is the problem. Lets say I select 28/11/2018 6:30 PM as the tour date and time. In the daterange picker it gets saved as

> 2018-11-28 18:30

```
$('input#tour_date').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    timePicker: true,
    timePickerIncrement: 30,
    locale: {
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A'
    }
}, function (chosendate) {
    $('input[name="tour_date"]').val(moment(chosendate).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm'));
    //the value for input becomes 2018-11-28 18:30
});
```

I have not set any timezone for daterangepicker or momentjs.
The datetime I get from the form (before saving to the database) is the same. i.e. it comes in as 2018-11-28 18:30.

However on saving to the database, it gets saved as

```
2018-11-28 01:00:00
```

It adds +06:30 (IST, Indian Standard Time value) to the incoming datetime field.

So when I open my calendar, the date is correct (28/11/2018) but the time is incorrect. The user saved the field expecting the time to be 6.30 PM but instead sees 01:00

I am saving the datetime as

```
var tourDate = new Date(req.body.tour_date).toISOString();
```

I am using Sequelize ORM and I have not given any specific timezone.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    pool: {
        max: 10,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    },
    logging: false
});
```

What I want to do is no matter which timezone the user is present in. I want to save the given date and time as is in the database and retrieve it as is, to be shown in the calendar.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Did you read the moment js manual carefully? Did you even wonder why it is always 11? And what number is November?

Comment: I changed the format string to 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm' on momentjs format, so the issue of the extra 11 mintues has been resolved. However it still saves the datetime by adding IST value to it

Comment: did you set a timezone in momentJS or fullCalendar? What about the webserver itself? How are you parsing the date when it arrives there? Have you debugged to see whether it still has the desired time when it arrives at the server (but before it is written into the database)? Does the mySQL server itself (not the sequelize connection) have a timezone set? Lots of missing info here.

Comment: I updated the information on my question. I am not setting timezone on momentjs, fullcalendar and daterangepicker. When the datetime arrives at the server, it is of the same format as in the input field.

Comment: So what about the webserver and mysql server? Any time settings on those? You didn't mention what you found there.

Comment: `(new Date()).toISOString()` will return UTC datetime (by adding/subtracting timezone offset to localtime... 18:30 - 05:30 = 01:00). You did not post the remaining details. But you could probably use moment js to convert local datetime to the format that MySQL expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are storing date via sequelize, then it will store the date as UTC ,**

So from the front end just pass the date in UTC , so it will get stored 
and if you are using date time picker it will automatically convert the UTC into your timezone , just pass the UTC data to your plugin.

**Just use UTC while passing and you are good to go.**

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do. I want to read the datetime value chosen by the user as is and save it as is, no matter what timezone the user is in. So far the only success is being able to get the selected datetime value at the server side in one piece but as soon as Sequelize saves it to the table it gets converted :(

Comment: So, you were right. It seems that I again need to convert the date on server side to utc using moment.

Comment: This does not work even with UTC option. Some how there are several settings that does not work. Node js really need a built-in, sequelize is poorly maintained. It looks like sequelize know nothing about time zones.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you use DATETIME data type in mysql, then value save as is
   independent on mysql time_zone system variable. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html).
2. mysql return different values for some functions depending on time_zone system varible. For example:

   ```
   SET time_zone='+00:00'; 
   SELECT now(); //2018-11-30 17-52-00

   SET time_zone='+03:00'; 
   SELECT now(); //2018-11-30 20-52-00
   ```
3. You can pass timezone option in sequelize to DB connetion. By default it
   '+00:00'. First of all, Sequelize use this value to set time_zone
   option on each connection (you can see it, if start Sequelize with
   DEBUG variable). Also Sequelize (or mysql2 package, i don't know) use timezone option to convert results returned by mysql to js Date objects. So:

   ```
   const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'user', 'password', {timezone: "+00:00"});

   sequelize.query('SELECT now() AS now;', {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
   //2018-11-30T17:52:00.000Z

   sequelize.query('SELECT createdAt FROM users WHERE userId = 1;', {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
   //2017-09-05T13:43:00.000Z


   const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'user', 'password', {timezone: "+03:00"});

   sequelize.query('SELECT now() AS now;', {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
   //2018-11-30T17:52:00.000Z

   sequelize.query('SELECT createdAt FROM users WHERE userId = 1;', {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
   //2017-09-05T10:43:00.000Z
   ```

Explain:

For `now`:

```
+-----------+---------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
| time_zone | mysql return        | sequelize read result as   | sequelize return         |
+-----------+---------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
|  +00:00   | 2018-11-30 17-52-00 | 2018-11-30 17-52-00 +00:00 | 2018-11-30T17:52:00.000Z |
+-----------+---------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
|  +03:00   | 2018-11-30 20-52-00 | 2018-11-30 20-52-00 +03:00 | 2018-11-30T17:52:00.000Z |
+-----------+---------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
```

For `createdAt`:

```
+-----------+---------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
| time_zone | mysql return        | sequelize read result as   | sequelize return         |
+-----------+---------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
|  +00:00   | 2017-09-05 13-43-00 | 2017-09-05 13-43-00 +00:00 | 2017-09-05T13:43:00.000Z |
+-----------+---------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
|  +03:00   | 2017-09-05 13-43-00 | 2017-09-05 13-43-00 +03:00 | 2017-09-05T10:43:00.000Z |
+-----------+---------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
```

So be carefully when set timezone option, when use DATETIME datatype. If you insert/select your data only with sequelize, then you don't need to change timezone option.

For correct work with datetime in my work, I use next rules:

- For transport datetime between client and server use uniquely determined format: [UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), [ISO 8601](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (string like `2017-09-05T13:43:00.000Z`);
- All DATETIME values in Mysql DB stores with zero timezone (+00:00); So timezone option for Sequelize is '+00:00';

Finally, browsers use time zone setting on your computer. Check the values at all steps and eliminate the uncertainties associated with incorrect interpretation of the time zone.

Comment: So here's what happening. I put timezone value to +00:00 in my sequelize. If I chose 05/12/2018 9:00AM in my calendar, it comes in as 2018-12-05T09:00:00 at my server side (before saving). But after the date is inserted, it become 2018-12-05 03:30:00.

Comment: @codeinprogress What format are you using for transport between client and server? Simple solution is send result of `dateString = date.toISOString()` from client and use `Date.parse(dateString)` on nodejs server.
Note that you should use time zone in this format for determined result, in ISO 8601 "Z" is "+00:00" time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after much confusion here is how this got solved. I had to convert the date at my client side to utc and then when it comes to my node.js server, I need to convert it to UTC again before saving it to database.

On client side I am setting the date in a hidden input field (which is what I am sending to server) using

```
$('input#tour_date').daterangepicker({
  singleDatePicker: true,
  showDropdowns: true,
  timePicker: true,
  timePickerIncrement: 30,
  locale: {
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A'
  }
}, function (chosendate) {
    //this is the hidden input where the set date is being sent
    $('input[name="tour_date"]').val(moment(chosendate).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'));
});
```

So one server it comes in as

> 2018-12-31T10:30:00.000Z

Which then I have to process again using moment like this:

```
moment.utc(req.body.tour_date); //this is saved to db
```

When I read the record and display it to the user I reprocess the date as

```
moment.utc(act.tour_date).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A')
```

So the user sees 31/12/2018 10:30 AM in the datepicker

I also pass `moment.utc(act.tour_date).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')` back to the hidden input, in case the user updates the record

Thank you everyone who helped me figure this out. Appreciate your time and efforts.